# Infinite loop with Algorithm2e

Tags: algorithm2e, pseudocode

I'm using `Algorithm2e` and want a loop with no intial condition and no ending condition. Using `Algorithmic`, this can be achieved with `\Loop ... \EndLoop`, but I cannot find a similar loop for `Algorithm2e`. How do I do this in `Algorithm2e`?

Comment: It's not very clear; can you make an example?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Something like this, with empty condition?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm2e}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\SetKwFor{Loop}{Loop}{}{EndLoop}

\begin{algorithm}
  \Loop{}{Statement\;Statement\;}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Or perhaps more elegantly
`\SetKwBlock{Loop}{Loop}{EndLoop}`